# Gostaria de uma ajuda, fiz todo o procedimento de cadastro e login e está funcionando

Tags: php, mysql

Gostaria de uma ajuda, fiz todo o procedimento de cadastro e login e está funcionando, porém faço login com email e me retornar o email(usuario) na tela quando faço login fica "olá, xxx@xxx.xxx" isso pq faço o login pelo email, mas queria que me retornasse o nome em vez do email mas continuando o login pelo email.

```
<?php
  if(isset($_SESSION['email'])): 
  include('verifica_login.php');
  ?>
  <img id="char" src="IMAGENS/ICONES/char2.ico" alt=""> <br>
  <h2 style="color:white;font-size:13px">Olá, <?php echo $_SESSION['email']; 
  ?></h2>
  <h2 style="color:white;font-size:13px"><a href="logout.php">Sair</a></h2>
  <?php
  endif;
  ?>
```

meu arquivo php

```
<?php
session_start();
include('coneccao.php');

if(empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['senha'])){
    header('Location: HOME.php');
    exit();

}

$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
$senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['senha']);

$query = ("select nome from usuario where email = '{$email}' and senha = md5('{$senha}')");

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

$row = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($row == 1){
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    header('Location: HOME.php');
    exit();
}else{
    $_SESSION['nao_autenticado'] = true;
    header('Location: HOME.php');
    exit();
}

?>
```

Comment: Se você seleciona o nome do banco de dados, por que armazena na sessão apenas o e-mail?

Answer (score 0):

Substitua por isso:

```
<h2 style="color:white;font-size:13px">Olá, <?php echo $_SESSION['nome']; 
?></h2>
```

e por isso:

```
if($row == 1){
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['nome'] = $row['nome'];
    header('Location: HOME.php');
    exit();
}else{
    $_SESSION['nao_autenticado'] = true;
    header('Location: HOME.php');
    exit();
}
```